# Copying block of data in SpreadsheetView to a bigger block does not work

Tags: java, javafx, spreadsheet, controlsfx

I am using the `SpreadsheetView` from ControlsFX. When I select multiple cells, copy them and paste them to a bigger block it does not work.

My code:

```
int rowCount = 5;
int columnCount = 3;
GridBase grid = new GridBase(rowCount, columnCount);

ObservableList<ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell>> rows = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

for (int row = 0; row < grid.getRowCount(); ++row) {
    final ObservableList<SpreadsheetCell> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    for (int column = 0; column < grid.getColumnCount(); ++column) {
        list.add(SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(row, column, 1, 1,"value"));
    }
    rows.add(list);
}

grid.setRows(rows);
spreadsheet.setGrid(grid);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title, the text of the question a little bit to make your question more precise. I also improved the formatting of the code a little bit. You should also try to be more specific about what you think is the problem. Which parts of your code do you think are part of the problem? Explain a bit what your code is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

It is not well explained in the SpreadsheetView documentation what is exactly supported in copy pasting. I will modify that.

To answer your question, if you copy one value towards several cells, the same value will be pasted everywhere in the selection.

If you copy several cells into one cell, the whole block will be pasted starting from the selected cell.

Now if you have a selection and you try to paste it in another selection (your case), it will fail unless your selection is a multiple of the original selection.
Selection a 2x3 can be pasted in a 4x6 selection. It can also be pasted into a 2x6 selection. But it will not be pasted into a 3x5 selection.
If you want a very specific behavior when pasting, you can override the pasteClipboard method (see https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/)